# JQuery screen size function along with scroll top

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a screen size to the function below but doesn't work. I'm stuck.
The following works...

```
$(document).ready(function(){


        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('.hoverItem').css("line-height", "55px");
                $('#header').css("background", "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)");
                $('#header').css("box-shadow", "0 4px 6px -6px #f8f8f8");           
            } else {
                $('.hoverItem').css("line-height", "105px");
                $('#header').css("background", "none");
                $('#header').css("box-shadow", "none");         
            }
        });

});
</script>
```

But when I add screen size it doesn't work...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 960) {

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('.hoverItem').css("line-height", "55px");
                $('#header').css("background", "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)");
                $('#header').css("box-shadow", "0 4px 6px -6px #f8f8f8");           
            } else {
                $('.hoverItem').css("line-height", "105px");
                $('#header').css("background", "none");
                $('#header').css("box-shadow", "none");         
            }
        });
    };
});
</script>
```

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Please define "it doesn't work", what errors do you get?

Comment: Please post the HTML and CSS so we can review that also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code, all window resize, load & scroll issue will be solved.. Just have to define values of `scrlTop` & `winWidth`.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    var scrlTop = 100;
    var winWidth = 960;

    function changeStyle(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > scrlTop && $(window).innerWidth() < winWidth) {
            $('.hoverItem').css("line-height", "55px");
            $('#header').css("background", "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)");
            $('#header').css("box-shadow", "0 4px 6px -6px #f8f8f8");           
        } else {
            $('.hoverItem').css("line-height", "105px");
            $('#header').css("background", "none");
            $('#header').css("box-shadow", "none");         
        }
    }

    changeStyle();

    $(window).on('scroll resize', function(){
        changeStyle();
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm a student and am still learning and your code not only works but has thought me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Dont see any problem with your code .... works fine:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 960) {
        console.log('window width: ' + $(window).width() + 'px');
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('#header').css("background", "blue");       
            } else {
                $('#header').css("background", "red");     
            }
        });
    };
});
```

```css
#header {
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  background:red;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:3000px;">
  <div id="header">HEADER</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but for some reason the width element doesn't seem to work.